# SQL: Conditional Percentage Increase

Tags: sql

Using Bartender custom SQL, I am attempting to add 20% to a label price if it is VAT applicable (i.e. if it has a tax ID of 2583)

The information for tax is stored in one database table called StockItem.TaxCodeID, and the price is stored in another called StockItemPrice.Price.

Is there a way to make this happen? I'm very new to SQL and have gotten by so far using the query and join tools included with bartender, and the code it generates makes logical sense to me.

```
SELECT "dbo"."StockItem"."Code", "dbo"."StockItem"."Name", "dbo"."StockItem"."TaxCodeID", "dbo"."StockItem"."PartNumber", "StockItemPrice"."Price" FROM "dbo"."StockItem" , "StockItemPrice"
WHERE "dbo"."StockItem"."ItemID" = "StockItemPrice"."ItemID" 
AND 
   ("StockItemPrice"."PriceBandID" = 1001 
      AND "dbo"."StockItem"."Code" LIKE '6%' 
      AND "dbo"."StockItem"."PartNumber" LIKE '%?BarcodeSearch1%' 
      AND "dbo"."StockItem"."Name" LIKE '%?NameSearch%' 
      AND "dbo"."StockItem"."TaxCodeID" = 258
```

Sorry in advance if I haven't provided enough information, I'll do my best to add more if needed!

Comment: Thank you for adjusting the code formatting for me Robert =)

Answer (score 0):

Use `case when` statement,

```
select *, CASE taxid
     WHEN taxid=2538 THEN price *1.20
     else price
END as newcolumn
from stockitem
```

Comment: Use proper capitalization, and format your code, please.  Note my edit.  I upvoted your answer.

Comment: No joy so far, although that looks like how I imagined it to look. I am going to work on it some more based on this suggestion. Cheers!